# Why does filtering an array come back with an error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I want to filter an array of text for numbers between 0 and 3.75 on google slides but it always comes back with an error and I don't know if the m variable isn't an array or if it's apps script being weird.

```
var text = shape.getText();
  let m = String(text).match(/[0-9.]{1,}/g);

  let r1 = m.filter(e => e >= 0 && e <= 3.75);
```

the error being

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')

text gets all the text inside the google slides
m gets all numbers between 0-9
r1 should filter all objects in m between 0 and 3.75, but here it breaks. is it because the match doesn't work with google slides?

Comment: [Edit] to quote the error.

Comment: Please Provide sample text.  It's hard to fix things you can't see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')

```
m.filter(e => e >= 0 && e <= 3.75);
```

This means that the variable `m` is `null`. `m` is the result of`String.match`.

```
  let m = String(text).match(/[0-9.]{1,}/g);
```

The result of `String.match` is `null` only when the regex doesn't match the `text`.

> [Return value: An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value)

Why doesn't `text` match the regex?

1. The shape doesn't actually contain numbers.
2. If the `shape` actually contains numbers(Which is more probable), the return of [`Shape.getText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#gettext) is not `String`, but `TextRange`

   ```
    var text = shape.getText();
   ```

   `text` is of type `TextRange` class. `String(TextRange)` doesn't get the raw data of the string in the shape, but a literal string `TextRange`.

#### Solution:

Call [TextRange.asString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#asstring) to get the raw data inside it as `String`.

#### Snippet:

```
  let m = text.asString().match(/[0-9.]{1,}/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my example:

```
function myfunk01() {
  let text = "0,1.0, 2.0 , 3.1, 4.2, 5.3, 6.4, 7.5, 8.6, 9.0, 9.5, 10";
  let m = text.match(/[0-9.]{1,}/g);
  let r1 = m.filter(e => e >= 0 && e <= 3.75);
  let r2 = m.filter(e => e >= 9.0 && e <= 9.75);
  Logger.log(r1.join(','))
  Logger.log(r2.join(','))
}
```

So please provide me with your example